# how to draw coordinates along the lanes using MultiLineString instead of LineString

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers, vector, features

I trying to draw lines along the path of the lanes on the map using openlayer3 but i am not getting any lines on the lanes there is no error in the developers console as well

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rotation example</title>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.2/build/ol.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="map" style="width:800px;height:800px"></div>
<script>
    var map;
    map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
            attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
                collapsible: false,
            })
        }),
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([103.986908, 1.353199]),
            rotation: 68*Math.PI/180,
            zoom: 18
        })
    });
    function plotLines(){

        var feature1 = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.MultiLineString([[[103.984889,1.350228], [ 103.986498,1.353864]], [[103.986498,1.353864], [103.988247,1.358454]]]),
            name: 'camera'
        });

        var featureStyle = new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Style({
                color: [0, 0, 0, 255],
                width: 10
            })
        });
        feature1.setStyle(featureStyle);

        vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [feature1]
        });
        /*t clear the markers*/
        /*vectorSource.clear();*/
        vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: vectorSource
        });
        map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
    }//
    plotLines();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am newbie please say me what is wrong i not sure of the approach to do it, trying few things to accomplish it  please if some body has code sample to do it please do post

Answer (score 1):

You have several faults within your code.

1. You have to transform as @itsyahani suggests your geometry.
   Better tranform the geometry it self and not the coords one by one.
   so this piece of your code

   ```
   var feature1 = new ol.Feature({
   geometry: new ol.geom.MultiLineString([[
   [103.984889,1.350228], 
   [103.986498,1.353864]], 
   [[103.986498,1.353864], 
   [103.988247,1.358454]]]),
   name: 'camera'
   });
   ```

should change to this

```
    var feature1 = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.MultiLineString([[
    [103.984889,1.350228], 
    [103.986498,1.353864]], 
    [[103.986498,1.353864], 
    [103.988247,1.358454]]]).transform('EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857'),
    name: 'camera'
    });
```

2. You declare your stroke color faulty. I guess this is a typo. But it wont work. So this piece of your code

```
var featureStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Style({
            color: [255, 255, 255, 255],
            width: 10
        })
    });
```

should change to this

```
var featureStyle = new ol.style.Style({
            stroke:     new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                width: 10
            })
        });
```

Comment: thank you but it is just providing a straight line not following the direction of the map can please post some sample of using any direction service of openlayers3 in order to do it

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform coordinates along the MultiLineString to the projection of the map like this,

```
    function plotLines(){
    var p1=ol.proj.transform([103.986908, 1.353199], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857");
    var p2=ol.proj.transform([ 103.986498,1.353864], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857");
    var p3=ol.proj.transform([103.986498,1.353864], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857");
    var p4=ol.proj.transform([103.988247,1.358454], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857");
    var feature1 = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.MultiLineString([[p1, p2], [p4, p3]]),
        name: 'camera'
    });

    var featureStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Style({
            color: [255, 255, 255, 255],
            width: 10
        })
    });
    feature1.setStyle(featureStyle);

    vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [feature1]
    });
    /*t clear the markers*/
    /*vectorSource.clear();*/
    vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource
    });
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
}//
```

Comment: thank you but it is just providing a straight line not following the direction of the map can please post some sample of using any direction service of openlayers3 in order to do it